# iPhone HUD style progress bar

Tags: iphone, progress-bar, hud

I've been wanting to create a HUD style loading bar like the SMS app on the iPhone used to have but I don't know how to. I was wondering if anyone has done this before or if there is a tutorial somewhere for it? I just think it looks so nice and would like to use it rather than the built in loading progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be very simple to implement using [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) layers (the [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer) class).

The bar would be a layer with rounded corners and the fill could be drawn by a custom drawing method.